# Spring dynamic injection generic type

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have multiple order types which each have a service which extends a generic service.

```
public abstract class OrderService<T extends Order> {

    private final OrderRepository<T> orderRepository;
    protected final RestService restService;

    public OrderService(OrderRepository<T> orderRepository, RestService restService) {
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
        this.restService = restService;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<T> getOpenOrders() {
        List<T> openOrders = return this.orderRepository.findByExecutionType(ExecutionType.OPEN);
    }

    public abstract boolean execute(T order);
}
```

(Note each order type has its own execute method)

I have a BaseOrderService which is the default:

```
@Service
@Primary
public class BaseOrderService extends OrderService {

   public BaseOrderService(OrderRepository orderRepository, ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher, RestService restService) {
       super(orderRepository, applicationEventPublisher, restService);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean execute(Order order) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Execution of a base order is not supported");
   }
}
```

Then I get all my orders in a single database call and execute them as follows:

```
    public void doSomething() {
        List<Order> openOrders = orderService.getOpenOrders();
        openOrders.forEach(order -> getService(order).execute(order));
    }

    public OrderService getService(Order order) {
        if (order instanceof LimitOrder) {
            return limitOrderService;
        } else if (order instanceof StopLossLimitOrder) {
            return stopLossLimitOrderService;
        } else if (order instanceof StopLossMarketOrder) {
            return stopLossMarketOrderService;
        } else if (order instanceof TrailingStopOrder) {
            return trailingStopOrderService;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Order type '" + order.getClass().getSimpleName() + "' not known");
        }
    }
```

My question, is there a better way then using `instanceof` to get the correct service?

Comment: Can you put `Order` interface in your post, please?

Comment: @Paul.F-G you mean the "Order" entity object?